# javascript/jQuery setTimeout and clearTimeout not working

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

This is a total noob problem. Sorry. I am using jQuery and ajax with php backend to check availability of usernames on keyup. I have this in my form.

```
Username <input id="uName" type="text" maxlength="20" name="username" /><br />
<span id="uNMessage">&nbsp;</span>
```

and this in my script

```
function unchk(){
    $('#uName').keyup(function(){
        var ab = $(this);
        if(ab.val().length > 4){
            $.ajax({url: "/php/username-check.php",type:'post',data:{username:$(this).val()},
                success: function(result){
                    if(result == 0){
                        ab.css("outline-color","red");
                        untmr('Username Already Taken');
                    }   
                    else if(result == 1){
                        ab.css("outline-color","#42c43b");
                        $('#uNMessage').html('&nbsp;');
                    }               
                }
            });
        }
        else{
            $(this).css("outline-color","red");
        }
    });
}//END FUNCTION UNCHK
function untmr(msg){
    clearTimeout(unto);
    unto = setTimeout(unmsg(msg),1500);
}
function unmsg(msg){
    $('#uNMessage').html(msg);
}
$(document).ready(function(){
    unchk();
    var unto;
});
```

When I declared the variable `unto` within `untmr()` it did not delay the execution of `unmsg()`, and when I changed it to global, it stopped executing altogether. Hmmm.

Comment: use quotes around the javascript in setTimeout: unto = setTimeout("unmsg(msg)",1500);

Comment: @hackartist: Passing a string to `setTimeout` is [not recommended](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout#section_2).

Answer (score 1):

Before you can assign to `unto`, you need to declare it.

```
var unto;
function untmr(msg){
    clearTimeout(unto);
    unto = setTimeout(unmsg(msg),1500);
}
```

and since you're *calling* `unmsg`, it will need to return a function that gets passed to `setTimeout`...

```
function unmsg(msg){
    return function() { $('#uNMessage').html(msg); }
}
```

Comment: @buck54321: Your declaration is in a variable scope that `untmr` doesn't have access to. Either put `untmr` into your `ready()` callback, or make `unto` global.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
function untmr(msg){
    clearTimeout(unto);
    unto = setTimeout(function(){unmsg(msg);} ,1500);
}
```